# Get column index from column name in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

In R when you need to retrieve a column index based on the name of the column you could do

```
idx <- which(names(my_data)==my_colum_name)
```

Is there a way to do the same with pandas dataframes?

Answer (score 640, accepted):

Sure, you can use `.get_loc()`:

```
In [45]: df = DataFrame({"pear": [1,2,3], "apple": [2,3,4], "orange": [3,4,5]})

In [46]: df.columns
Out[46]: Index([apple, orange, pear], dtype=object)

In [47]: df.columns.get_loc("pear")
Out[47]: 2
```

although to be honest I don't often need this myself.  Usually access by name does what I want it to (`df["pear"]`, `df[["apple", "orange"]]`, or maybe `df.columns.isin(["orange", "pear"])`), although I can definitely see cases where you'd want the index number.

Comment: Column number is useful when using `.iloc` operator, where you must pass only integers for both rows and columns.

Comment: Or when using libraries which want the DF converted to a numpy array and indices of columns with particular features. For example CatBoost wants a list of indices of categorical features.

Comment: Is there a way to get list of indexes?

Comment: In my case I want to use the index of the column get values of "itertuples" by column name. Fetching the indeces of the column names instead of hardcoding keeps it dynamic in case of changes to the DF.

Comment: it's also useful for the insert function (to enable you to insert after a given column)

Comment: This works good for superficially figuring out the column number in an excel file based on a df column header, after writing that df with xlsxwriter.

Answer (score 76):

Here is a solution through list comprehension. cols is the list of columns to get index for:

```
[df.columns.get_loc(c) for c in cols if c in df]
```

Answer (score 21):

For returning multiple column indices, I recommend using the `pandas.Index` method [`get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html), if you have **unique labels**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"pear": [1, 2, 3], "apple": [2, 3, 4], "orange": [3, 4, 5]})
df.columns.get_indexer(['pear', 'apple'])
# Out: array([0, 1], dtype=int64)
```

If you have **non-unique labels** in the index (columns only support unique labels) [`get_indexer_for`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer_for.html). It takes the same args as `get_indexer`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"pear": [1, 2, 3], "apple": [2, 3, 4], "orange": [3, 4, 5]}, 
    index=[0, 1, 1])
df.index.get_indexer_for([0, 1])
# Out: array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Both methods also support **non-exact indexing** with, f.i. for float values taking the nearest value with a tolerance. If two indices have the same distance to the specified label or are duplicates, the index with the larger index value is selected:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"pear": [1, 2, 3], "apple": [2, 3, 4], "orange": [3, 4, 5]},
    index=[0, .9, 1.1])
df.index.get_indexer([0, 1])
# array([ 0, -1], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 18):

DSM's solution works, but if you wanted a direct equivalent to `which` you could do `(df.columns == name).nonzero()`

Answer (score 13):

When you might be looking to find multiple column matches, a vectorized solution using [`searchsorted` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) could be used. Thus, with `df` as the dataframe and `query_cols` as the column names to be searched for, an implementation would be -

```
def column_index(df, query_cols):
    cols = df.columns.values
    sidx = np.argsort(cols)
    return sidx[np.searchsorted(cols,query_cols,sorter=sidx)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [162]: df
Out[162]: 
   apple  banana  pear  orange  peach
0      8       3     4       4      2
1      4       4     3       0      1
2      1       2     6       8      1

In [163]: column_index(df, ['peach', 'banana', 'apple'])
Out[163]: array([4, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 13):

**Update: "Deprecated since version 0.25.0: Use np.asarray(..) or DataFrame.values() instead." pandas docs**

In case you want the column name from the column location (the other way around to the OP question), you can use:

```
>>> df.columns.values()[location]
```

Using @DSM Example:

```
>>> df = DataFrame({"pear": [1,2,3], "apple": [2,3,4], "orange": [3,4,5]})

>>> df.columns

Index(['apple', 'orange', 'pear'], dtype='object')

>>> df.columns.values()[1]

'orange'
```

Other ways:

```
df.iloc[:,1].name

df.columns[location] #(thanks to @roobie-nuby for pointing that out in comments.)
```

Comment: `df.columns` is a useful way to access a specific col of a csv

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'get_values'` (python 3.8.8 pandas 1.3.1)

Comment: @SanjayManohar get_values deprecated since pandas version 0.25.0: Use np.asarray(..) or DataFrame.values() instead. (answer updated)

Answer (score 10):

To modify DSM's answer a bit, `get_loc` has some weird properties depending on the type of index in the current version of Pandas (1.1.5) so depending on your Index type you might get back an index, a mask, or a slice.  This is somewhat frustrating for me because I don't want to modify the entire columns just to extract one variable's index. Much simpler is to avoid the function altogether:

```
list(df.columns).index('pear')
```

Very straightforward and probably fairly quick.

Answer (score 5):

When the column might or might not exist, then the following (variant from above works.

```
ix = 'none'
try:
     ix = list(df.columns).index('Col_X')
except ValueError as e:
     ix = None  
     pass

if ix is None:
   # do something
```

Answer (score 4):

how about this:

```
df = DataFrame({"pear": [1,2,3], "apple": [2,3,4], "orange": [3,4,5]})
out = np.argwhere(df.columns.isin(['apple', 'orange'])).ravel()
print(out)
[1 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import random
def char_range(c1, c2):                      # question 7001144
    for c in range(ord(c1), ord(c2)+1):
        yield chr(c)      
df = pd.DataFrame()
for c in char_range('a', 'z'):               
    df[f'{c}'] = random.sample(range(10), 3) # Random Data
rearranged = random.sample(range(26), 26)    # Random Order
df = df.iloc[:, rearranged]
print(df.iloc[:,:15])                        # 15 Col View         

for col in df.columns:             # List of indices and columns
    print(str(df.columns.get_loc(col)) + '\t' + col)
```

![Results]([Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8VH8.png)

Comment: This does ... something, but without any explanation is not of any use.