# Pandas: Apply function via "Column A", simultaneously reading "Column B"

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using `Pandas` to drive a `Python` function. From `inputs.csv`, I use each row in `"Column A"` as an input for the function.

In the `csv`, there is also a `"Column B"` that contains values that I want to read into a variable `x` within the function. It should not `apply` from `"Column B"` – this should still be done from `"Column A"`. Is this possible?

---

This is the current code that applies the function from `"Column A"`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(inputs.csv, delimiter=",")

def function(a):
    #variables c, d, e are created here
    ###I would like to create x from Column B if possible
    return pd.Series([c, d, e])
df[["Column C", "Column D", "Column E"]] = df["Column A"].apply(function)
```

---

*Post-edit:* This question has been identified as a possible duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698). Although the answer may be the same, the *question* is not the same. For future readers it is probably not apparent that `apply` on two columns is interchangeable with `apply` on one column and "reading" another column at the same time. The question should therefore remain open.

Comment: Not sure if I get your question right, but maybe what you want is simply `df[(['Column A', 'Column B'])].apply(scrape, axis=1)`, this means you get still just one argument to your function `scrape`, but that argument is a tuple of the values of `Column A` and `Column B`

Comment: @firelynx Thanks for your reply. I don't need to combine the columns in any way – `Column A` still holds the keyword for the argument. I only need to read `Column B` and pass it to a variable. If I run the argument by `axis=1`, how do I select `Column A` for `def function(a)` from the tuple?

Comment: inside `def function(a):` you would simply need to have one row like this: `col_a, col_b = a`

Comment: Made an answer with a bit more clairty.

Comment: Where do you want to "create x"? Should it end up in the dataframe or just live inside the function? Should x be a Series or just a variable?

Comment: @firelynx It just needs to live inside the funcition as a variable :) I will use it simply to `print` the contents, so it doesn't need to be `returned`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply a function to two columns of Pandas dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are currently using [`Series.apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) , instead you can use - [`DataFrame.apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply), with `axis=1` to get each row in the function , then you can access the columns as - `row[<column>]`.

Example -

```
In [37]: df
Out[37]:
   X  Y  Count
0  0  1      2
1  0  1      2
2  1  1      2
3  1  0      1
4  1  1      2
5  0  0      1

In [38]: def func1(r):
   ....:     print(r['X'])
   ....:     print(r['Y'])
   ....:     return r
   ....:

In [39]: df.apply(func1,axis=1)
0
1
0
1
1
1
1
0
1
1
0
0
Out[39]:
   X  Y  Count
0  0  1      2
1  0  1      2
2  1  1      2
3  1  0      1
4  1  1      2
5  0  0      1
```

This is just a very simple example, you can modify this to what you really want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works now! My only issue is that it reads the top row 2 times before moving on to the next. Then there is no more repetitions. Do you have any idea why (if it has anything to do with the `DataFrame.apply()` vs `Series.apply()`.

Comment: No, it does not have anything to do with `Series.apply` vs `DataFrame.apply` . Are you sure the dataframe itself does not have same row twice at top? Check my example , its not reading first row twice (its just that first and second row are identical) .

Comment: To cross check, try printing the `index` of the row to see if its actually the same row twice.

Comment: I checked the index and it's correct. The problem must lie in how I pass on the argument to the function. (I am not using your literal example). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `axis=1` argument passed to [the apply method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) puts the whole row into [the apply method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) as a single tuple argument.

This is however *a lot* slower than applying with a single column. I would advice against this if performance is an issue.

```
def scrape(x):
    a, b = x
    # Magically create c, d, e from a
    print(b)
    return pd.Series([c, d, e])

df[["Column C", "Column D", "Column E"]] = df[(['Column A', 'Column B'])].apply(scrape, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm not sure if I understand correctly, I have probably been unclear – `a` and `b` is not the same nor should be combined. What I would like to do is use `a` as the argument for the function, as in my original code. `b` should only be passed on to `x` as `x = b`. So if I run `def function(a)`, how can I include `b` in that function?

Comment: @Winterflags Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got a strange JSON error with your solution, `is not JSON serializable`. I am sure it would've worked but I wasn't able to solve it atm.