# Calculate development factor using pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

The development factor from time *t* to time *t+1* is A<sub>t+1</sub> / A<sub>t</sub>. I am trying to apply this calculation to a pandas DataFrame that looks something like below:

```
   T0   T1   T2
0  100  200  250
1  80   120  150
```

Starting from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe), I tried the following

```
f = lambda x: np.divide(x[1], x[0])
df.applymap(f, axis=1)
```

but I am getting an error an index error. I would like the output to be

```
   T0_T1  T1_T2
0  2.0    1.25
1  1.5    1.25
```

Comment: what is the error? you should post the error message too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need change `applymap` to `apply`:

```
f = lambda x: np.divide(x[1], x[0])
df1 = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df1)
0    2.0
1    1.5
dtype: float64
```

If function is more complicated:

```
def f(x):
    print (x)
    #add code
    return x.T1 / x.T0

df1 = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df1)
0    2.0
1    1.5
dtype: float64
```

But better is used vectorized faster solution with [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
print (df.T1.div(df.T0))
0    2.0
1    1.5
dtype: float64
```

---

```
print (df.T1 / df.T0)
0    2.0
1    1.5
dtype: float64
```

EDIT by commnet:

Divide by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)ed df, last remove first column by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1 = df.div(df.shift(axis=1))
print (df1)
   T0   T1    T2
0 NaN  2.0  1.25
1 NaN  1.5  1.25

df1 = df1.iloc[:,1:]
print(df1)
    T1    T2
0  2.0  1.25
1  1.5  1.25
```

Comment: I edited the question to clarify my intention, I understand how to divide two individual columns but I want to apply the calculation to the entire DataFrame,