# How to compare two columns of the same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
 match_id inn1  bat  bowl  runs1 inn2   runs2   is_score_chased
    1     1     KKR  RCB    222  2      82          1
    2     1     CSK  KXIP   240  2      207         1
    8     1     CSK  MI     208  2      202         1
    9     1     DC   RR     214  2      217         1
   33     1     KKR  DC     204  2      181         1
```

Now i want to change the values in **is_score_chased** column by comparing the values in **runs1** and **runs2** . If runs1>runs2, then the corresponding value in the row should be **'yes'** else it should be **no**.
I tried the following code:

```
for i in (high_scores1):
  if(high_scores1['runs1']>=high_scores1['runs2']):
      high_scores1['is_score_chased']='yes'
  else:
      high_scores1['is_score_chased']='no'
```

But it didn't work. How do i change the values in the column?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can more easily use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
high_scores1['is_score_chased'] = np.where(high_scores1['runs1']>=high_scores1['runs2'], 
                                           'yes', 'no')
```

Typically, if you find yourself trying to iterate explicitly as you were to set a column, there is an abstraction like `apply` or `where` which will be both faster and more concise.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good case for using [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe) there is an example of using apply on two columns.

You can adapt it to your question with this:

```
def f(x):    
   return 'yes' if x['run1'] > x['run2'] else 'no'

df['is_score_chased'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

However, I would suggest filling your column with booleans so you can make it more simple

```
def f(x):    
   return x['run1'] > x['run2']
```

And also using lambdas so you make it in one line

```
df['is_score_chased'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['run1'] > x['run2'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the fact that you are iterating through the dataframe, so;

```
for i in (high_scores1):
  if(high_scores1['runs1'][i]>=high_scores1['runs2'][i]):
      high_scores1['is_score_chased'][i]='yes'
  else:
      high_scores1['is_score_chased'][i]='no'
```