# read_csv get the line where exception occured

Tags: python, pandas, exception

The HTTP log files I'm trying to analyze with pandas have sometimes unexpected lines. Here's how I load my data :

```
df = pd.read_csv('mylog.log',
            sep=r'\s(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)(?![^\[]*\])', 
            engine='python', na_values=['-'], header=None,
            usecols=[0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,10],
            names=['ip', 'time', 'request', 'status', 'size', 
                'referer','user_agent','req_time'], 
                converters={'status': int, 'size': int, 'req_time': int})
```

It works fine for most of the logs I have (which come from the same server). However, upon loading some logs, an exception is raised :
    either

```
 TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a  number, not 'NoneType'
```

or

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"GET /agent/10577/bdl HTTP/1.1"'
```

For the sake of the example, here's the line that triggers the second exception:

```
22.111.117.229, 22.111.117.229 - - [19/Sep/2018:22:17:40 +0200] "GET /agent/10577/bdl HTTP/1.1" 204 - "-" "okhttp/3.8.0" apibackend.site.fr 429282
```

To find the number of the incriminated line, I used the following (terribly slow) function :

```
def search_error_dichotomy(path):    
        borne_inf = 0
        log = open(path)
        borne_sup = len(log.readlines())
        log.close()
        while borne_sup - borne_inf>1:
            exceded = False
            search_index = (borne_inf + borne_sup) // 2
            try:
                pd.read_csv(path,...,...,nrows=search_index)
            except:
                exceded = True
            if exceded:
                borne_sup = search_index
            else:
                borne_inf = search_index

        return search_index
```

What I'd like to have is something like this :

```
try:
    pd.read_csv(..........................)
except MyError as e:
    print(e.row_number)
```

where e.row_number is the number of the messy line.

Thank you in advance.

> 

***SOLUTION***
All credits to devssh, whose suggestion not only makes the process quicker, but allows me to get all unexpected line at once. Here's what I did out of it :

1. Load the dataframe without converters.

   ```
   df = pd.read_csv(path,
                    sep=r'\s(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)(?![^\[]*\])', 
                    engine='python', na_values=['-'], header=None,
                    usecols=[0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,10],
                    names=['ip', 'time', 'request', 'status', 'size',
                    'referer', 'user_agent', 'req_time'])
   ```
2. Add an 'index' column using .reset_index() .

   ```
   df = df.reset_index()
   ```
3. Write custom function (to be used with apply), that converts to int if possible, otherwise saves
   the entry and the 'index' in a dictionary wrong_lines

   ```
   wrong_lines = {}
   def convert_int_feedback_index(row,col):
       try:
           ans = int(row[col])
       except:
           wrong_lines[row['index']] = row[col]
           ans = pd.np.nan
       return ans
   ```
4. Use apply on the columns I want to convert (eg col = 'status', 'size', or 'req_time')

   ```
   df[col] = df.apply(convert_int_feedback_index, axis=1, col=col)
   ```

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: @devssh : Yes I tryed with small nrows, the error occurs at line 271119. As for removing the converters and using .astype or .apply, that sounds like a good idea yet I don't know how to retrieve the number of the row where the exception occurs.

Comment: Did you see my suggestion of `reset_index`? It will give you `index` column with row numbers. Combine that with `apply` over multiple columns and you can customize everything. You seem to be getting the row numbers now by default with this alternative approach right?

Comment: @devssh : Wow, using 'df.reset_index()' will indeed do the trick! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `pd.read_csv(..., nrows=10)` to see if it works on even 10 lines?

Perhaps you should not use `converters` to specify the `dtypes`.
Load the DataFrame then apply the dtype to columns like `df["column"] = df["column"].astype(np.int64)` or a custom function like `df["column"]=df["column"].apply(lambda x: convert_type(x))` and handle the errors yourself in the function convert_type.
Finally, update the csv by calling `df.to_csv("preprocessed.csv", headers=True, index=False)`.
I don't think you can get the line number from the `pd.read_csv` itself. That separator itself looks too complex.

Or you can try just reading the csv as a single column DataFrame and use `df["column"].str.extract` to use regex to extract the columns. That way you control how the exception is to be raised or the default value to handle the error.

`df.reset_index()` will give you the row numbers as a column. That way if you [apply to two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe), you will get the row number as well. It will give you index column with row numbers. Combine that with apply over multiple columns and you can customize everything.