# Add a new column to python DataFrame with switch-case like of regEx

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to append a new column to a `pandas.DataFrame()` with the result on each row to be a switch case of different regEx. 
New to python I discover that there is now switch/case loop so I have to do it with if/elif/else.

My first approach (and fail) was to do :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
...
wrangle = wd()
df['groupe_canaux'] = wrangle.regex_canaux(df)
```

Then in my wrangle class :

```
class WrangleData:

    ...

    def regex_canaux(self, df):
        if df['medium'] == "(NONE)":
            return "Direct"
        elif df['medium'] == "(NOT SET)":
            return "BAR"
        elif re.match("(.*)app_id=cpcg$", df['landingPage']):
            return "SEA"
        else:
            return "FOO"
```

I have ~20 regEx to add inn the final version checking up to 4 differents col values to add the good string in the new column.

Here I got the error : `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

EDIT : Further search lead me to `DataFrame.apply()`. But I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found out how to do it with `df.apply()` thanks to this post : [How to apply a function to two columns of Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe)

data_to_df.py

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
...
wrangle = wd()
df['groupe_canaux'] = df.apply(lambda x: wrangle.regex_canaux(x.medium), axis=1)
```

wrangle_data.py

```
class WrangleData:

    ...

    def regex_canaux(self, df):
        if df['medium'] == "(NONE)":
            return "Direct"
        elif df['medium'] == "(NOT SET)":
            return "BAR"
        elif re.match("(.*)app_id=cpcg$", df['landingPage']):
            return "SEA"
        else:
            return "FOO"
```

Then after a `print(df.head())` I got :

```
        date          medium  sessions groupe_canaux
0 2019-02-25          (NONE)     11173        Direct
1 2019-02-25       (NOT SET)        12           BAR
2 2019-02-25  ABTESTING-HOME       126           FOO
3 2019-02-25       AFFILIATE         1           FOO
4 2019-02-25         ANNONCE         1           FOO
```