# How to use the apply function to a function with multiple variables?

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a dataset of the following format:

```
msgText                   name
'My name is Donald'       Donald
'I am married to Jenny'   Donald 
'Donald is from Europe'   Donald
```

What I would like to do is replace parts of the `msgText` column fs it contains the name from the `name` column and I would like to replace it by 'Karl'. So that my desired output looks as follows:

```
msgText                   name
'My name is Karl'         Donald
'I am married to Jenny'   Donald 
'Karl is from Europe'     Donald
```

To do so, I have the following function:

```
def replaceName(text, name):
    newText = text.replace(name, 'Karl')
    return newText
```

However, I don't know how to apply this function to a Pandas series.

What I started with is:

```
dataset['filtered_text'] = dataset.msgText.apply(replaceName)
```

However, here I don't take the name coluimn into consideration. How can I use the apply function and use two columns as input variables to my function?

Comment: Have a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply a function to two columns of Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: You can use a `lambda` function here: `df['msgText'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['msgText'].replace(x['name'], 'Karl'), axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution you are looking for:

```py
df['msgText'] = df.apply(lambda row: replaceName(row['msgText'], row['name']), axis=1)

print(df)
                   msgText     name
0        'My name is Karl'   Donald
1  'I am married to Jenny'   Donald 
2    'Karl is from Europe'   Donald
```