# Previous and next array should have two much common values pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like ,

```
Test              Test1
[1,1,1]          [1,2,2]
[1,2,2]          [1,0,1]
[1,0,1]          [1,1,0]
[2,2,0]          [0,2,2]
[1,2,0]          [1,0,2]
```

I am trying to compare the two arrays where 2 numbers should match and third one should be o.So like   `[1,0,1]   [1,1,0]`  should be matched and return true as two numbers are matching and third one is 0 . same for `[2,2,0]          [0,2,2]`  but `[1,2,0]          [1,0,2]`  this should not match as it does not have the same numbers.will return false. So,Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Each 3-tuple is judged individually?  Or in pairs of 3-tuples?

Comment: Can you explain what should be `True` and `False` in the comparison in more detail? Why is `[1,2,0]` and `[1,0,2]` evaluated to `False`. Contains two matching numbers and zeros.

Comment: I mean it does not have the same number it's 1 and 2. So because of that.. if it would have [1,0,1] and [1,1,0] then it would have been true

Comment: two tuples should exact match and third one should be 0

Comment: And you need the second 3-tuple to have the same numbers as well? So `[1,1,0]` and `[2,2,0]` would evaluate to false?

Comment: yes this evaluate to false

Comment: But one should be 0 from both. 2 number should match

Comment: Did you try coding the logic?

Comment: One more -  will the nonzero integers always be positive?

Comment: Yes they always be positive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the testing function you need (I think, assuming all values are positive)

```
def test_func(x):
    A = x[0]
    B = x[1]
    f = lambda X: np.unique(X, return_counts = True)
    Au, Ac = f(A)
    Bu, Bc = f(B)
    return np.all(Au == Bu) and \ 
           Au.size == 2 and  \     
           Ac[0] == 1 and \        
           Bc[0] == 1
```

And to apply in in `pandas` (not a pandas expert, but I think this should work):

```
df['new_col'] = df[['Test', 'Test1']].apply(test_func, axis = 1)
```

in any case, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe) should help you apply your function over two columns.

Comment: Something unexpected char it is giving for  \

Comment: get rid of the comments

Comment: could you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991053/create-a-sub-columns-in-the-dataframe-using-a-another-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment104233258_58991053

Answer (score 0):

Using this function, you can compare two tuples and check if they fulfill your requirements:

```
def eval_tuples(tup1, tup2):
    # Check if zeros occures once in each tuple
    if tup1.count(0) != 1 or tup2.count(0) != 1:
        return False

    # Get non-zero values
    rem1 = [x for x in tup1 if x != 0]
    rem2 = [x for x in tup2 if x != 0]

    # Check if they are equal in both tuples
    if rem1[0] != rem1[1] or rem2[0] != rem2[1]:
        return False
    return True
```

Here some example runs of the function:

```
print(eval_tuples([1,1,0], [1,0,1]))
# True
print(eval_tuples([1,1,0], [2,0,1]))
# False
print(eval_tuples([2,2,0], [0,2,2]))
# True
print(eval_tuples([1,2,0], [1,0,2]))
# False
```

Comment: Hey, so what If I try to match [1,2,0]  and  [1,0,2] . How will it be ?

Comment: Added some exmple runs in the answer

Comment: No No, Here I was asking, If I want [1,2,0] and [1,0,2]  this type of condition I want to be true that time

Comment: In your question you write: "... `[1,2,0]          [1,0,2]` this should not match as it does not have the same numbers.will return false. ...".

Comment: If you want `[1,2,0]` and `[1,0,2]` to be evaluated to `True`, simply replace `if rem1[0] != rem1[1] or rem2[0] != rem2[1]:` with `set(rem1) == set(rem2):`!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```py
>>> def compare_tuples(x, y):
...     return (
...         # there is any series of size two which is common in both tuples
...         any(x[i:i+2] == y[j:j+2] for i in range(2) for j in range(2))
...         # there is at least one zero at third position
...         and 0 in (x[2], y[2])
...     )

>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
...     [(1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2)],  # False
...     [(1, 2, 2), (1, 0, 1)],  # False
...     [(1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0)],  # True - (1, 0) matches and 0 in third position
...     [(2, 2, 0), (0, 2, 2)],  # True - (2, 2) matches and 0 in third position
...     [(1, 2, 0), (1, 0, 2)],  # False
... ], columns=["Test1", "Test2"])

>>> df.apply(lambda x: compare_tuples(*x), axis=1)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```