# Use two columns as inputs - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new column that comes from the calculation of two columns. Usually when I need to do this but with only one column I use `.apply()` but now with two parameters I don't know how to do it.

With one I do the following code:

```
from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame

df = read_csv('results.csv')

def myFunc(x):
  x = x + 5
  return x

df['new'] = df['colA'].apply(myFunc)

df.head()
```

With two I thought was like the following, but not.

```
from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame

df = read_csv('results.csv')

def myFunc(x,y):
  x = x + y
  return x

df['new'] = df[['colA','colB']].apply(myFunc)

df.head()
```

I see some people use `lambda` but I don't understand and furthermore I think has to be easier.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply a function to two columns of Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `axis=1` and in function access columns like below

```
def myFunc(x):
    x['colA']
    x['colB']
```

and you apply it as

```
 df['new'] = df.apply(myFunc, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: avoid `apply` if possible. With that in mind, you are looking for `axis=1`, but you need to rewrite the function like:

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: myFunc(x['colA'], x['colB']), 
                     axis=1)
```

which is essentially equivalent to:

```
df['new'] = [myFunc(x,y) for x,y in zip(df['colA'], df['colB'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Get knowledge of using lambda from here

> lambda function is an expression
> https://realpython.com/python-lambda/

> The special syntax *args in function definitions in python is used to
> pass a variable number of arguments to a function
>
> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/

```
from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame

df = read_csv('results.csv')

def myFunc(x,y):
  return x + y

df['new'] = df[['colA','colB']].apply(lambda col: myFunc(*col) ,axis=1)

df.head()
```