# pandas - 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make a function to create a new column with the following parameters.

```
import pandas as pd 

data = {'weekdaystart': ['Monday', 'Monday'], 'weekdayend': ['Monday', 'Tuesday'],'starthour': [7,21] ,'endhour':[15,7]}
dc = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

def lol(dt,col1,col2,col3,col4):
    for i in dt.index:
        a = dt[col1].iloc[i]
        b = dt[col2].iloc[i]
        c = dt[col3].iloc[i]
        d = dt[col4].iloc[i]

        if a == b:
            if 7 < c <= 15 and 7 < d <= 15:            
                return d - c
            else:
                
                return 0
        else:
            
            return 
            
dc['Weekday_Day_hr'] = dc.apply(lol(dc,'weekdaystart','weekdayend','starthour','endhour'))
```

But I am getting 'int' object is not callable.
The expected result for dc['Weekday_Day_hr'] the first row would be 15-7 and for the second row would be 0. I am not sure if I did the def lol wrong, or should I try with iterrows()?

Comment: You can not use `dc.apply(lol(dc, ...))`, since lol will return an `int` (for example `0`, and then you thus have `dc.apply(0)`, but apply expects a *callable*.

Comment: apply receives a function..., you are calling the function inside apply and the function returns and int

Comment: Sorry I am still a novice here, how would I use the function to create that column without apply? is there a different method that I can use? or should I assign the math to a variable and then return the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `apply` is a good idea here, but I'm not sure you understand it correctly. Some reading materials before jumping in to your problem:

1. [`apply` at Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)
2. [How to apply a function to two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe). This also demonstrates us how to define our own function and call it using `apply`.

So some issues with your `lol` function:

1. No need to loop over the dataframe indices, `apply` does that for us (and more efficiently).
2. if the `a==b` condition is not met, your return is empty. You should return some value, or None (Honestly I'm not sure if `return` alone returns None.. if it does, you can ignore this remark)

Putting it all together:

```py
def lol(df):
    a = df['weekdaystart']
    b = df['weekdayend']
    c = df['starthour']
    d = df['endhour']

    if a == b:
        if 7 <= c <= 15 and 7 <= d <= 15:  # I changed "<" to "<="            
            return d - c
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        return None # Not sure if None is needed

dc['Weekday_Day_hr'] = dc.apply(lol, axis=1)
```

Not sure it works exactly according to your expected results, was following your code rather than actually trying to understand why it gives None at the second row and not 0 as you asked.

Comment: Thank you! I see what you mean. I also tried the following: `def lol(dt,col1,col2,col3,col4):
    for i in dt.index:
        a = dt[col1].iloc[i]
        b = dt[col2].iloc[i]
        c = dt[col3].iloc[i]
        d = dt[col4].iloc[i]

        if a == b:
            if 7 <= c <= 15 and 7 <= d <= 15:            
                return d - c
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            return  0  dc['Weekday_Day_hr'] = lol(dc,'weekdaystart','weekdayend','starthour','endhour') but for some reason it brings 8 to both rows` but yours works as expected @itaishz