# How to send values from different pandas columns to a function that is used in the apply function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column email, that would combine data from two columns: email_first_part and domain.

```
def new_email_column(first_part, domain):
    if first_part == "nan" & domain =="":
        return missing 
    else:
        return first_part + "@" + domain



df["new_email"] = df["new_email"].apply(df.loc["email_first_part"], df.loc["domain"])
```

The new_email column, uses values from other two columns, check for conditions given in function, and updates the values.
I am getting an error, when I try to do this. How to I get this working. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
df["new_email"] = df.apply(lambda x: new_email_column(x["email_first_part"], x["domain"]), axis=1)
```

As you want to use data in other columns, you cannot use `apply()` on the "new_email" column (i.e. pandas Series `df["new_email"]`) as in your original code `df["new_email"]).apply(...)`.   You have to use the apply on the the whole DataFrame `df` (or selected columns with the specific columns you want to use).

You need to add `axis=1` to the `apply()` function so as to work on the column axis (i.e. perform row-wise operation with passing row data with all columns to your `apply()` function).  Without `axis=1`, you are working on columns one by one where you can only access the row-index rather than column indice/labels.

Using the lambda function allows you to call your custom function new_email_column() without modification of the function.  Otherwise, you need to amend the function to include one more parameter for the passed-in row Series).

If you want to better understand this convention of using `apply(..., axis=1)` and also explore another calling convention with better system performance (execution time), you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66034370/pandas-custom-function-to-find-whether-it-is-the-1st-2nd-etc-monday-tuesday-e) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way to do this would be to replace the empty strings with `NaN` and then just concatenate the columns. It is always good to keep missing values as `NaNs` rather than a string.

```
df = df.replace({'': np.nan})
df['new_email'] = df['email_first_part'] + '@' + df['domain']
```

Input

```
  email_first_part       domain
0              abc    gmail.com
1              xyz  outlook.com
2              NaN
```

Output

```
  email_first_part       domain        new_email
0              abc    gmail.com    abc@gmail.com
1              xyz  outlook.com  xyz@outlook.com
2              NaN          NaN              NaN
```

Comment: So, I am using some functions and when apply on columns, if the column type is str, python throws an error, since nan values are float. is there anyway to fix this ?

Comment: Vectorize them and pandas will handle better than pure python. By vectorized I mean try not to use apply whenever possible.