# How to select values based on array's index from relative index within pandas groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame, which is already sorted by the columns `('year', 'month')`, that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021],
    'month': [1, 2, 5, 2, 4, 7, 9],
    'values': [
        ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    ]
})

print(df)

    year    month   values
0   2020    1       ['a', 'b', 'c']
1   2020    2       ['a', 'b', 'c']
2   2020    5       ['a', 'b', 'c']
3   2021    2       ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
4   2021    4       ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
5   2021    7       ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
6   2021    9       ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

I want to create a new column named `'value'`, which contains the value of the *i-th* element on the `'values'` array, where *i* is the index of the corresponding month, grouped by year. In this case, the outcome would be:

```
    year    month   values                  value
0   2020    1       ['a', 'b', 'c']         'a'
1   2020    2       ['a', 'b', 'c']         'b'
2   2020    5       ['a', 'b', 'c']         'c'
3   2021    2       ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']    'A'
4   2021    4       ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']    'B'
5   2021    7       ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']    'C'
6   2021    9       ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']    'D'
```

I'm assuming there is no data missing on the arrays. Some lines I've tried involve using `.groupby('year')` followed by `.get_loc('month')`, but couldn't get the correct result so far.

EDIT:

There is one detail I forgot to mention: The months are not necessarily in a uniform range, therefore the index is not always `month-1`. I've edited the DataFrame in question to reflect this nuance.

Comment: See my edit of answer according to your edit that the index is not always `month-1`.

Comment: Edited according to data sample change also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use [`df.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on `axis=1`:

```
df['value'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['values'][x['month']-1], axis=1)
```

### Alternatively, use [`list([map()])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) for [better system performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66034661/15070697) (execution time) for large data:

```
df['value'] = list(map((lambda x, y: x[y]), df['values'], df['month'] - 1))
```

Output:

```
   year  month        values value
0  2020      1     [a, b, c]     a
1  2020      2     [a, b, c]     b
2  2020      3     [a, b, c]     c
3  2021      1  [A, B, C, D]     A
4  2021      2  [A, B, C, D]     B
5  2021      3  [A, B, C, D]     C
6  2021      4  [A, B, C, D]     D
```

### Edit: (According to OP's Edit that "index is not always `month-1`")

In response to OP's edit after the answer is posted, that:

> The months are not necessarily in a uniform range, therefore the index
> is not always month-1.

While the following requirement, mentioned in the original version of question, still holds true:

> I want to create a new column named 'value', which contains the value
> of the i-th element on the 'values' array, where i is the index of the
> corresponding month, grouped by year.

The solution will be amended in as follows:

***Step 1:  Create index of the corresponding month, within the group that is grouped by year***

Setup column `value_idx` by [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) together with [`Series.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.transform.html) as follows:

### Use `x.index - x.index[0]` within [`Series.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.transform.html) to get the relative index within pandas groups.

```
df['value_idx'] = df.groupby('year')['values'].transform(lambda x: x.index - x.index[0])

print(df)

   year  month        values  value_idx
0  2020      1     [a, b, c]          0
1  2020      2     [a, b, c]          1
2  2020      5     [a, b, c]          2
3  2021      2  [A, B, C, D]          0
4  2021      4  [A, B, C, D]          1
5  2021      7  [A, B, C, D]          2
6  2021      9  [A, B, C, D]          3
```

*The values in column `value_idx` are set up independent of the values of `month` and are the relative index within the respective year groups.*

***Step 2:  Set up column `value` according to index in column `value_idx` independent of column `month` values***

Set up column `value` with either [`df.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) or [`list(map())`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

Either:

```
df['value'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['values'][x['value_idx']], axis=1)
```

or:

```
df['value'] = list(map((lambda x, y: x[y]), df['values'], df['value_idx']))
```

print(df) Output:

```
   year  month        values  value_idx value
0  2020      1     [a, b, c]          0     a
1  2020      2     [a, b, c]          1     b
2  2020      5     [a, b, c]          2     c
3  2021      2  [A, B, C, D]          0     A
4  2021      4  [A, B, C, D]          1     B
5  2021      7  [A, B, C, D]          2     C
6  2021      9  [A, B, C, D]          3     D
```

Optionally, you can clean up the column `value_idx` if desired:

```
df = df.drop(columns='value_idx')
```

print(df) Output:

```
   year  month        values value
0  2020      1     [a, b, c]     a
1  2020      2     [a, b, c]     b
2  2020      5     [a, b, c]     c
3  2021      2  [A, B, C, D]     A
4  2021      4  [A, B, C, D]     B
5  2021      7  [A, B, C, D]     C
6  2021      9  [A, B, C, D]     D
```

Answer (score 3):

#### comprehension

```
df.assign(value=[v[m-1] for v, m in zip(df['values'], df['month'])])

   year  month        values value
0  2020      1     [a, b, c]     a
1  2020      2     [a, b, c]     b
2  2020      3     [a, b, c]     c
3  2021      1  [A, B, C, D]     A
4  2021      2  [A, B, C, D]     B
5  2021      3  [A, B, C, D]     C
6  2021      4  [A, B, C, D]     D
```

---

#### Alternative `map` with `list.__getitem__`

```
df.assign(value=[*map(list.__getitem__, df['values'], df['month'] - 1)])
```

Answer (score 3):

Let us try `lookup`

```
df['out'] = pd.DataFrame(df['values'].tolist(),index=df.index).lookup(df.index,df.month-1)
df
Out[372]: 
   year  month        values out
0  2020      1     [a, b, c]   a
1  2020      2     [a, b, c]   b
2  2020      3     [a, b, c]   c
3  2021      1  [A, B, C, D]   A
4  2021      2  [A, B, C, D]   B
5  2021      3  [A, B, C, D]   C
6  2021      4  [A, B, C, D]   D
```

For the future people since the `lookup` is going to be removed

```
df['out'] = pd.DataFrame(df['values'].tolist(),index=df.index).values[df.index,df.month-1]
```