# Optimizing a nested loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: 'VENDOR_ID' and 'GL_Transaction_Description'. I want to print every row of the 'GL_Transaction_Description' column that has any value from the 'VENDOR_ID' column.

| VENDOR_ID | GL_Transaction_Description |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | HELLO 345 |
| 456 | BYE 456 |
| 987 | THANKS 456 |

The desired output here would be 'BYE 456' AND 'THANKS 456.
My code is as such:

```
for k in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(len(df)):
        if df['VENDOR_ID'][k] in df['GL_Transaction_Description'][j] and df['VENDOR_ID'][k] != 'nan':
            print(df['GL_Transaction_Description'][j])
```

But this particular dataframe counts more than 100k rows and it takes forever to run with a nested for loop. Any ideas on how to make this execute faster? I have read that using numpy usually makes things go blazingly faster but I haven't been able to implement it.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.  Can you posta sample data and expected result?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish either, but OP should look for boolean masks (as in ashkangh awnser) and the apply method.

Comment: @CFreitas Sorry about that, I edited it

Comment: since you are using two loops can I assume that if you have a third row: ID=789, GL="Hello 456", this value should also return?

Comment: @CFreitas yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Boolean Mask`

```
v_list = df['VENDOR_ID'].to_list()
mask = list(map((lambda x: any([(y in x) for y in v_list])), df['GL_Transaction_Description']))

print(df['GL_Transaction_Description'][mask])
```

Assumed 'VENDOR_ID' is already in dtype of str.  If not, then change the line `mask = ....` to:

```
mask = list(map((lambda x: any([(str(y) in x) for y in v_list])), df['GL_Transaction_Description']))
```

We can do it with `df.apply()` with `axis=1`. However, `list(map())` has [better system performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66034370/pandas-custom-function-to-find-whether-it-is-the-1st-2nd-etc-monday-tuesday-e/66034661#66034661) (execution time) than `df.apply()` on `axis=1`.

Output:

```
1       BYE 456
2    THANKS 456
Name: GL_Transaction_Description, dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice, but this only works for the matching elements in the same row. I want matching elements that exist in the whole of the VENDOR_ID column. (check my re-edited question)

Comment: @JohnMantios  Amended as per your clarification.

Comment: Thanks a lot!What if I wanted to retrieve the indexes of the matching elements?

Comment: @JohnMantios  I have added link for reference of the better system performance of using `list(map())` as compared to `apply()` on `axis=1`.  It could be around 3x ~ 4x times faster in some cases.

Comment: @JohnMantios If you just want the index, use `df['GL_Transaction_Description'][mask].index`

Comment: You are the boss

Answer (score 0):

You can use `boolean Indexing`

```
df.loc[df['GL_Transaction_Description'].isin(df['VENDOR_ID']), 'GL_Transaction_Description']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean indexing with the `isin` function

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'VENDOR_ID': list('abcde') + ['matching_item'],
                  'GL_Transaction_Description': ['trx_descr_' + c for c in list('abcde')] + ['matching_item']})
df

    VENDOR_ID       GL_Transaction_Description
0   a               trx_descr_a
1   b               trx_descr_b
2   c               trx_descr_c
3   d               trx_descr_d
4   e               trx_descr_e
5   matching_item   matching_item

df[df.GL_Transaction_Description.isin(df.VENDOR_ID)].GL_Transaction_Description

5    matching_item
Name: GL_Transaction_Description, dtype: object
```