# Apply a function to rows within a DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, numpy

Assume I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [120,108.6], 'B': [109, 147]})
```

Assume I have the following function:

```
def cpt_p(A, B):
    n = np.arange(1, B+1)
    p = [A] * B # Creates a repeating value of A of length B i.e. [A, A, A, ...]
    return p * n
```

Could someone show how I'd apply this to my df? The following does not work:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(cpt_p(df[0], df[1]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Don't forget good old list comprehension `df["C"] = [cpt_p(x,y) for x,y in zip(df["A"], df["B"])]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can **use lambda function within `.apply()`** and access the column values by syntax like `x['A']` for column `A` values, etc.  For each function parameter, just put the corresponding `x['A']`, `x['B']` at the correct position of the function call, like `cpt_p(x['A'], x['B'])` for passing value of column `A` as first parameter and value of column `B` as second parameter (for each row):

```
def cpt_p(A, B):
    p = [A] * int(B) # Creates a repeating value of A of length B i.e. [A, A, A, ...]
    return p


df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: cpt_p(x['A'], x['B']), axis=1)
```

**Another method:**

Another method to apply a function to rows is by `list(map())`, like below:

```
df['C'] = list(map(cpt_p, df['A'], df['B']))
```

You can put the function as the first parameter to `map()` function and pass the function parameters as second parameter onwards to `map()`.

The advantage of using `list(map())` is that it is generally faster than using `apply()` on `axis=1`.  **Could be more than 3x times faster execution time.**  You can see [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66034661/15070697) for the execution time comparison for some use cases.

**Result:**

```
print(df)

       A    B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  C
0  120.0  109  [120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, ...]
1  108.6  147  [108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, 108.6, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a much simpler way to go about it.

```
df["C"] = df["B"].apply(lambda x: np.ones(x))*df["A"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you get the following Type error:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

There is a minor change required in the cpt_p function. The value that list gets multiplied to should be an integer.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [120,108.6], 'B': [109, 147]})

def cpt_p(A, B):
    n = np.arange(1, B+1)
    p = [A] * int(B) # Creates a repeating value of A of length B i.e. [A, A, A, ...]
    return p * n


df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: cpt_p(x['A'],x['B']), axis=1)

print(df)
```