# Apply lambda function to list of columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, string-to-datetime

I have a large dataframe from csv (170 cols). Many of these are date but not being read as date. I have a list of these as

`date_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'date' in col]` 
I want to apply a function to all those columns (13 total) How can i apply a function over that list. Attempted so far:

`modDfObj = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x) if x.name in date_cols else x)`

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13337376/15062605

Answer (score 1, accepted):

via `filter` and `applymap`

```
df = df.filter(like='date').applymap(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce'))
```

Updated:

```
date_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'date' in col]
df[date_cols] = df[date_cols].applymap(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce'))
```

Comment: That works but only returns a reduced data frame, can i return the full df with date columns converted in place?