# Add new column by lambda function raised a value error in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda

I have a data frame called df, and would like to add a column "Return" based on the existing columns by using lambda function. For each row, if value of "Field_3" < 50, then "Return" value would be the value of "Field_1", otherwise it would be "Field_2" value. My code raised a value error: Wrong number of items passed 7, placement implies 1. I'm a Python beginner, any help would be appreciated.

```
values_list = [[15, 2.5, 100], [20, 4.5, 50], [25, 5.2, 80],
           [45, 5.8, 48], [40, 6.3, 70], [41, 6.4, 90],
           [51, 2.3, 111]]


df = pd.DataFrame(values_list, columns=['Field_1', 'Field_2', 'Field_3'])

df["Return"] = df["Field_3"].apply(lambda x: df['Field_1'] if x < 50 else df['Field_2'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax here is a little tricky. You want:

```
def col_sorter(x, y, z):
    if z < 50:
        return x
    else:
        return y

df['return'] = df[['Field_1', 'Field_2', 'Field_3']].apply(lambda x: col_sorter(*x), axis=1)

out:
Field_1  Field_2  Field_3  return
0       15      2.5      100     2.5
1       20      4.5       50     4.5
2       25      5.2       80     5.2
3       45      5.8       48    45.0
4       40      6.3       70     6.3
```

Here's what's going on:

1. Define a function `col_sorter` that takes in the variables from one row of the dataframe and does what you want with it. (This isn't strictly necessary, but it's a good habit to form since not every transformation you want to do will be as simple as this, and this syntax scales.)
2. Then call `apply` off the columns you want from the dataframe, and pass them as a tuple to be unpacked into your function as a lambda function. (That's what the `*x` is doing).

This pattern will let you create a new column from arbitrarily complex calculations based on other columns in the dataframe, and while not as fast as vectorization is pretty fast.

For a lot more detail and discussion, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe).

Welcome to python and StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank you so much, BLimitless. Great to learn lambda function further.

Comment: When you call `apply` here, you're calling it off ['Field_1', 'Field_2', 'Field_3']. The `apply` takes one row containing entries from each of those columns and passes it into the function as a `series`. The `*x` catches that `series` and lets the function unpack it into the individual variables the function expects.

Comment: Fantastic. I didn't know lambda can be used in this way. Thanks a lot.