# Efficient way to get indices of column-labels from pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have this method where I grab the columns from a `pandas dataframe` depending on the labels but indexing via `numpy` is much faster.

**Is there a way in `pandas` or `numpy` to go from column labels to column indices without iterating?**

```
DF_var = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,10)), columns=["attr_%d" % _ for _ in range(10)])
query_cols = ["attr_2","attr_5","attr_6","attr_0"]
want_idx = [0,2,5,6]

# Something like np.where w/o iterating through? 
# np.where(query_cols in DF_var.columns)
# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

# np.where(x in DF_var.columns for x in query_cols)
# (array([0]),)


long_way = list()
for i, label in enumerate(DF_var.columns):
    if label in query_cols:
        long_way.append(i)
# print(sorted(long_way))
# [0, 2, 5, 6]
```

[image]

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021654/retrieving-column-index-from-column-name-in-python-pandas

Comment: Is this for a single value or for a list?

Comment: @O.rka single, but you can use a list comprehension to get all the indices.

Comment: This does the job using numpy `np.argwhere(DF_var.columns.isin(["attr_2","attr_5","attr_6","attr_0"])).flatten()`

Comment: @O.rka You can use `searchsorted method`. New answer posted into the linked dup target.

Comment: @Divakar hey thanks, do you have to turn into a `pd.categorical object`?  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Index.searchsorted.html

Comment: Well easiest way was to extract the column names as array and then using NumPy's searchsorted func. Here's the [`solution`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38489403/3293881).

Comment: Since, you don't care about the order, you can simply do : `np.where(np.in1d(df.columns,query_cols))[0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
short_way = [df.columns.get_loc(col) for col in query_cols]
print(sorted(short_way))
# outputs [0, 2, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Oh ok, so it still has to iterate through?

Comment: @O.rka Yes. AFAIK there is no vectorized way.