# Access values in a dataframe based on index and values in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

How do i get the value from a dataframe based on a list of index and headers?

These are the dataframes i have:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns=['a','b','c'])
referencingDf = pd.DataFrame(['c','c','b'])
```

Based on the same index, i am trying to get the following dataframe output:

```
outputDf = pd.DataFrame([3,6,8])
```

Currently, i tried this but would need to take the diagonal values. Am pretty sure there is a better way of doing so:

```
a.loc[referencingDf.index.values, referencingDf[:][0].values]
```

Comment: Wait, are you trying to get `a[referencingDf[0]]`?

Comment: yeap, thats right!

Comment: Then, what's your question, again?

Comment: How i can reference a to get the following outputDf based on referencingDF. essentially a[0]['c'], a[1]['c'], a[2]['b'].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `df.get_value` in a list comprehension.

```
vals = [a.get_value(*x) for x in referencingDf.reset_index().values]
# a simplification would be [ ... for x in enumerate(referencingDf[0])] - DYZ
print(vals) 
[3, 6, 8]
```

And then, construct a dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(vals)
print(df)

   0
0  3
1  6
2  8
```

Comment: `... for x in enumerate(referencingDf[0])` ?

Comment: @DYZ Definitely another choice, assuming `referencingDf` has a rangeIndex for columns (might not always be so).

Answer (score 5):

You need [`lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
b = a.lookup(a.index, referencingDf[0])
print (b)
[3 6 8]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'vals':b}, index=a.index)
print (df1)
   vals
0     3
1     6
2     8
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to use list comprehension:

```
vals = [a.loc[i,j] for i,j in enumerate(referencingDf[0])]
# [3, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one vectorized approach that uses [`column_index`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38489403/) and then [`NumPy's advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) for indexing and extracting those values off each row of dataframe -

```
In [177]: col_idx = column_index(a, referencingDf.values.ravel())

In [178]: a.values[np.arange(len(col_idx)), col_idx]
Out[178]: array([3, 6, 8])
```