# Specific pandas columns as arguments in new column of df.apply outputs

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

Given a pandas DataFrame as below:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(  
         {'row': ['a','b','c','d','e','y'],
            'a': [ 0, -.8,-.6,-.3, .8, .01],
            'b': [-.8,  0, .5, .7,-.9, .01],
            'c': [-.6, .5,  0, .3, .1, .01],
            'd': [-.3, .7, .3,  0, .2, .01],
            'e': [ .8,-.9, .1, .2,  0, .01],
            'y': [ .01, .01, .01, .01,  .01, 0],
       }).set_index('row')
df.columns.names = ['col']
```

I want to create a new column of RMSE values (from [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html)) using specific columns for the arguments.  Namely, the columns `y_true = df['a','b','c']` vs `y_pred = df['x','y','x']`.  This was easy to do using an iterative approach:

```
for tup in df.itertuples():
    df.at[tup[0], 'rmse']  = mean_squared_error(tup[1:4], tup[4:7])**0.5
```

And that gives the desired result:

```
col     a     b     c     d     e     y      rmse
row                                              
a    0.00 -0.80 -0.60 -0.30  0.80  0.01  1.003677
b   -0.80  0.00  0.50  0.70 -0.90  0.01  1.048825
c   -0.60  0.50  0.00  0.30  0.10  0.01  0.568653
d   -0.30  0.70  0.30  0.00  0.20  0.01  0.375988
e    0.80 -0.90  0.10  0.20  0.00  0.01  0.626658
y    0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.00  0.005774
```

But I want a higher-performance solution, possibly using vectorization, since my dataframe has shape (180000000, 52).  I also dislike indexing by tuple position rather than by column name.  The attempt below:

```
df['rmse'] = df.apply(mean_squared_error(df[['a','b','c']], df[['d','e','y']])**0.5, axis=1)
```

Gets the error:

```
TypeError: ("'numpy.float64' object is not callable", 'occurred at index a')
```

So what am I doing wrong with my use of `df.apply()`?  Does this even maximize performance over iteration?

### Testing Performance

I've tested the wall times for each of the first two respondants using the below test df:

```
# set up test df
dim_x, dim_y = 50, 1000000
cols = ["a_"+str(i) for i in range(1,(dim_x//2)+1)]
cols_b = ["b_"+str(i) for i in range(1,(dim_x//2)+1)]
cols.extend(cols_b)
shuffle(cols)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,10,[dim_y, dim_x]), columns=cols)  #, index=idx, columns=cols
a = df.values

# define column samples
def column_index(df, query_cols):
    cols = df.columns.values
    sidx = np.argsort(cols)
    return sidx[np.searchsorted(cols,query_cols,sorter=sidx)]

c0 = [s for s in cols if "a" in s]
c1 = [s for s in cols if "b" in s]
s0 = a[:,column_index(df, c0)]
s1 = a[:,column_index(df, c1)]
```

The results are as follows:

```
%%time
# approach 1 - divakar
rmse_out = np.sqrt(((s0 - s1)**2).mean(1))
df['rmse_out'] = rmse_out

Wall time: 393 ms

%%time
# approach 2 - divakar
diffs = s0 - s1
rmse_out = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',diffs,diffs)/3.0)
df['rmse_out'] = rmse_out

Wall time: 228 ms

%%time
# approach 3 - divakar
diffs = s0 - s1
rmse_out = np.sqrt((np.einsum('ij,ij->i',s0,s0) + \
         np.einsum('ij,ij->i',s1,s1) - \
       2*np.einsum('ij,ij->i',s0,s1))/3.0)
df['rmse_out'] = rmse_out

Wall time: 421 ms
```

The solution using the apply function is still running after several minutes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

One approach for performance would be to use the underlying array data alongwith NumPy ufuncs, alongwith slicing those two blocks of columns to use those ufuncs in a vectorized manner, like so -

```
a = df.values
rmse_out = np.sqrt(((a[:,0:3] - a[:,3:6])**2).mean(1))
df['rmse_out'] = rmse_out
```

**Approach #2**

Alternative faster way to compute the RMSE values with `np.einsum` to replace the `squared-summation` -

```
diffs = a[:,0:3] - a[:,3:6]
rmse_out = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',diffs,diffs)/3.0)
```

**Approach #3**

Another way to compute `rmse_out` using the formula :

> (a - b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab

would be to extract the slices :

```
s0 = a[:,0:3]
s1 = a[:,3:6]
```

Then, `rmse_out` would be -

```
np.sqrt(((s0**2).sum(1) + (s1**2).sum(1) - (2*s0*s1).sum(1))/3.0)
```

which with `einsum` becomes -

```
np.sqrt((np.einsum('ij,ij->i',s0,s0) + \
         np.einsum('ij,ij->i',s1,s1) - \
       2*np.einsum('ij,ij->i',s0,s1))/3.0)
```

---

**Getting respective column indices**

If you are not sure whether the columns `a,b,..` would be in that order or not, we could find those indices with [`column_index`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38489403/).

Thus `a[:,0:3]` would be replaced by `a[:,column_index(df, ['a','b','c'])]` and `a[:,3:6]` by `a[:,column_index(df, ['d','e','y'])]`.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions! I did a wall time comparsion of your three solutions and added it to my original post.

Comment: @ThomasMatthew Awesome! Good to see those timings.

Comment: Getting a `MemoryError` at larger DF sizes, which fails at the equivalent of `a[:,column_index(df, ['d','e','y'])]`.  Is there another way to accomplish approach 2 directly from the dataframe rather than creating a copy of the values with `a=df.values` which may be taking up more memory than needed?

Comment: @ThomasMatthew With all floating point values in the input dataframe, `df.values` would just be a view into the input dataframe and not a copy. Additionally let me ask you - Would cols - `a,b,c` always be column numbers `0,1,2` and `d,e,y` as `3,4,5` with 0-based indexing?

Comment: @Divakar Yes, I can know the column numbers ahead of time, and they should always be on 0-based indexing

Comment: @ThomasMatthew Well I meant if the column numbers are in sequence like `0,1,2` for the first slice. then as mentioned at the start of my post, use : `a[:,0:3]` instead of `a[:,column_index(df, c0)]` and similarly for the second slice. `a[:,column_index(df, c0)]` was forcing a copy there, whereas `a[:,0:3]` would be a view.

Comment: @Divakar I understand what you're saying now.  I can preprocess the dataframe so each group is contiguous, and can therefore use a slicing view.

Comment: @ThomasMatthew You got it.

Comment: @Divakar memory error persists at the step `diffs = a[:,1:26] - a[:,26:27]`.  Any suggestions on how to chunk this operation?

Comment: @ThomasMatthew That looks like the best we could do I am afraid.

Answer (score 2):

The df.apply approach:

```
df['rmse'] = df.apply(lambda x: mean_squared_error(x[['a','b','c']], x[['d','e','y']])**0.5, axis=1)

col     a     b     c     d     e     y      rmse
row                                              
a    0.00 -0.80 -0.60 -0.30  0.80  0.01  1.003677
b   -0.80  0.00  0.50  0.70 -0.90  0.01  1.048825
c   -0.60  0.50  0.00  0.30  0.10  0.01  0.568653
d   -0.30  0.70  0.30  0.00  0.20  0.01  0.375988
e    0.80 -0.90  0.10  0.20  0.00  0.01  0.626658
y    0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.00  0.005774
```