# How to get the position of certain columns in dataframe - Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Alex',10,'100k'],['Bob',12,'200k'],['Clarke',13,'300k']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age','Salary'])

col = ['Age','Salary']
```

How to get the position of columns in dataset df.
for an example , position of columns present in col list are 1 and 2 respectively. I want to get the position of these columns of col in list.

Comment: For a vectorized one - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38489403/ from the linked Q&A.

Comment: `[np.where(df.columns.values == cl)[0][0] for cl in col]`